# Craft CMS 3 error in Windows installation process

Tags: craft3

I was tried to run Craft 3 on a Windows machine, it has shown the multiple errors.

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\InvalidConfigException: craft\web\Request::cookieValidationKey must be configured with a secret key. in D:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php:1554
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php(1536): yii\web\Request->loadCookies()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get that error (regardless of OS) if the `SECURITY_KEY` variable isn't set in your `.env` file: https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/master/.env.example#L5

See this step in the install docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html#step-3-set-a-security-key

If you run the `craft setup` terminal command, it will generate that key for you, but depending on how you install Craft, you can also manually set it.